# Import into EntityForms, Drupal

Tags: excel, csv, drupal, entity, feed

I am having an excel sheet with columns `"First Name" & "Last Name"`. I want to create an Entity Form with same fields, after creating the form I would like to import the data from a CSV file(generated from excel sheet). Can you suggest to me how to achieve this goal? I have tried "Feeds" with Patches but in the end I am getting `"Unable to set the data property created as the parent data structure is not set"` error.

I would request you to please upload a video if possible, it will light up others way to acheive this goal.

Answer (score 0):

First you create, the entity form with these two fields and then use [Feed import](https://www.drupal.org/project/feed_import) module. Make sure, you will use same field name which you created in your Entity form.
Refer, https://www.drupal.org/node/2285537

You missed something, but it is not very clear to me. It's very easy to find out the problem if you will attache the screenshot/scenario.